# Rich Text Box Load Problem ? I Counldn't load Rich Text Box to Bread in Laravel Voyager?

Tags: richtextbox, voyager

I'm working with Php laravel Voyager framework . 
I try to add new field with fieldType is Rich text box but it doesn't work?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Voyager's default option which mentioned in the below screenshot;
[image: Rich Text Box Option in the dropdown list]

If this doesn't work for you or you want to add Rich Text Editor/another field, then [this](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/adding-custom-formfields) link can helps you.